# Integrating a open source java lib on grails application

Tags: java, grails, apache-tika

I want to intergate the [apache tika](http://tika.apache.org/) jar or source files into my grail application and how can i do it please ...

**what about access source files into my groovy controller or something**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot's of way to include jar on a grails project, however i think that te best way is using maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
 </dependency>
```

add on your BuildConfig.groovy file

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile'org.apache.tika:tika-core:1.7'
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try grails apache tika plugin http://grails.org/plugin/tika-parser

Comment: did you mean, it is not supported?

Comment: thanks ;) 
I could not find any other plugin..
Though you can certainly call TIKA classes in your grails application.. Or please elaborate what you want to achieve.

Comment: changed my name.. :-P

Answer (score 1):

there is a thrird option.  you can put the downloaded .jar file into the `/lib` dir of your grails project.  do `grails package` and it should get picked up.  this of course is a much inferior solution, than just using a plug-in or dependencies, but might come handy.

Comment: what about access source files into my groovy controller or something

Comment: what do you mean?  source-jars or just the plain source?  and what do you mean by "access"?

Comment: source java files classess

Comment: sorry, i don't follow.  are you talking about the sources for the library you are using?  what ide are you using?  intellij e.g. can disasm the classes or allows you to attach downloaded source files.

Comment: dude the hthing is to access class files and implemation function on a grails project /.//how that sound ?